# Admob does not allow apps rated 12+ or medium maturity?

Tags: admob

I am trying to advertise an app on Admob and it was disapproved for policy/content violations with no explanation. After e-mailing for clarification, they simply copy/pasted the required Apple ratings information, such as the following, however they left out all the "Infrequent" references:

- Infrequent/Mild Horror/Fear Themes
- Infrequent/Mild Mature/Suggestive Themes
- Infrequent/Mild Profanity or Crude Humor
- Infrequent/Mild Alcohol, Tobacco, or Drug Use or References
- Infrequent/Mild Sexual Content or Nudity

The app is rated 12+, essentially the same as "medium maturity" for Android apps. I find it very difficult to believe that they would only allow apps rated for everyone to advertise on their network. The ad itself was even targeted for males 18-24+. It's a music/social network app, and rated as such for possible lyric content that users control.

I just searched some apps on the Android market and see a sniper game where you kill and shoot people, rated medium maturity, that has admob ads just fine. This is actually far more violent than a music app that may have "naughty lyrics".

Is this just some gripe between Google/Admob employees and Apple that they don't like the terms Apple uses for their content rating? Has anyone else had this problem getting an ad approved and is there any solution other than putting out an update, modifying content rating, and hoping Apple approves it so then Admob doesn't cry about Apple's content rating terminology?